# How to read back embedded OLE object Tika parser?

Tags: java, apache-poi, ole, apache-tika

I am using Tika/tika-app-1.17.jar to extract out a MS-PowerPoint (.pptx) having two slides - 1 slide consists of an embedded Excel s/sheet (I assume is an OLE automation object).  The second is just a normal slide with content.

My problem is trying to read back the extracted parts of the .pptx (specifically the embedded Excel s/sheet) into a Java VM using Apache POIFS.  POI is not recognizing the resulting slide1_rId3_oleObject1.bin as an embedded OLE object.  Running PowerShell (gc command) shows me that the binary file does have the correct 'header'  - here is the first 30 bytes dumped:

```
d0  cf  11  e0  a1  b1  1a  e1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3e  0  3  0  fe  ff
```

I have tried reading the file back in as a DocumentInputStream, as well as trying to realize it as an Ole10Native - from POIFS, without much success.

I do note the following when Tika extracts the .pptx parts.  This is Tika run with the --list-parser-details option turned on (and -v for verbose):

```
org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser (Composite Parser):
  org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser (Composite Parser):
     org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser (Wrapped by With Types)
        text/plain
     org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser (Wrapped by With Types)
        application/pdf
     org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlParser (Wrapped by With Types)
        text/html
        application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml
        application/x-asp
        application/xhtml+xml
     org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser (Wrapped by With Types)
        application/x-tika-msoffice-embedded; format=ole10_native
        application/msword
        application/vnd.visio
        application/vnd.ms-project
more output...
     org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser (Wrapped by With Types)
        application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroenabled.12
        application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroenabled.12
        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
        application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroenabled.12
        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
more output...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <meta name="X-Parsed-By" content="org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser"/>
   <meta name="X-Parsed-By" content="org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser"/>
   <meta name="resourceName" content="sample.pptx"/>
   <meta name="Content-Length" content="1536"/>
   <meta name="Content-Type" content="application/x-tika-msoffice"/>
   <title/>
  </head>
  <body/>
 </html>
```

I can share the code (in Java) I used to try and realize the embedded .bin file.  However, I have yet to see a concrete example of someone reading back one of these 'embedded OLE' files extracted from Tika, using POIFS.  Is this even possible - or is there a more efficient way to do this - that I am overlooking?

Thanks for any guidance or a code-sample someone can provide.

Comment: Did you try running the Tika App in `-z` mode to dump the embedded resources, then running Tika a second time on the OLE2 embedded resources found within?

Comment: Good suggestion, I re-ran Tika on the embedded oleObject.bin resource, with the following command: `java -jar .\tika-app-1.17.jar -v --config=.\tika-config.xml -m --list-parser-details .\oleObject1.bin` and I receive the following: `Content-Length: 28672
Content-Type: application/x-tika-msoffice
X-Parsed-By: org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser
X-Parsed-By: org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser
resourceName: oleObject1.bin`

Comment: What is very confusing is how Tika treats `application/x-tika-ms-office` from `application/x-tika-msoffice-embedded; format=ole10_native`.  Wouldn't the second item be the content-type for an extracted OLE2 embedded/automation resource?

Comment: Run it a second time with `-z` - you've got lots and lots of layers of wrappers going on!

Comment: Thanks @Gagravarr.  I plan to run through the 'Tika parse/passes' with Tika running in my debugger to see exactly what is going on in more depth.  I shall report back soon. 8^)

Comment: I have been running portions of unit-tests for  tika-parser and have noticed one interesting tidbit.  When I open (in Office/PPT 2016)    test_ppt_embedded_two_slides.pptx and copy/paste what appears to be an embedded worksheet back to Excel (same revision), you are unable to directly select items inside Excel.  I had to do a double-click - which caused another Excel window to open - and the Excel window/title shows the items (pasted) as a worksheet.  Seems like there is a level of indirection.  Running -z (or  --extract) did not unpack anything further in the earlier example.

Comment: More to this @Gagravarr - the embedded portion is a package located directly within the OOXML structure (confirmed with    POIVisualizer).  The content-type was     application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.oleObject.  I then noticed I could rename the 1st-level oleObject1.bin as a ZIP file (Tika would _not_ perform any additional extraction - reported it as     application/x-tika-msoffice).  When I unpacked the ZIP using 7-zip, the resulting 'package' could then be opened in Excel 2016.  No double-click to edit the worksheet contents.